# Validate image dimensions - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to do a validation where uploaded image cannot have width or height more than 1024px. This is what I did, but it doesn't work every time for some reason:

```
readThumbUrl(event: any) {
        this.thumbnailFile = [];
        const eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
        const target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
        const files: FileList = target.files;
        if (files) {
            this.thumbnailFile.push(files[0]);
        }

        var image;

        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
                this.thumbUrl = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
// This part is for validation
                image = new Image();
                image.src = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
// Here, sometimes it takes width 0 and sometimes it takes image width,
// dont know for what reason.
                if (image.width > 1024 || image.height > 1024) {
                    this.dimensionError = true;
                }
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }

        this.videoModel.thumbnail = event.target.value;
    }
```

So validation sometimes triggers, sometimes does not, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The best approach is to validate it in server-side instead of client-side.

Comment: @NirajPaudel It is done one server side as well, however i need to validate it before I make api call :/